# How to create separate tar files from separate directories and to copy to /tmp directory

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a requirement like I have to create the tars from folders like

```
"/xyz/test1/abc1/"
"/xyz/test1/abc2/"
"/xyz/test3/abc3/"
```

I have to create tars like `abc1.tar` , `abc2.tar` , `abc3.tar` in each respective  directories and  copy to `~/tmp` directory any bash script would help me out.  I have like 16 such folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tar archiving that takes input from a list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033857/tar-archiving-that-takes-input-from-a-list-of-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can tar all **abc** directories together with below,

```
tar -cvf abc.tar /xyz/test*/abc*
```

if need to have separate tar files, then

```
cat DirList.txt
   /xyz/test1
   /xyz/test2
   /xyz/test3
```

feed the directory list into a loop,

```
    i=1                          // **i** - variable to to make the file names unique
    while read dirName
    do
       cd ${dirName}                 // --> change directory
       tar -cvf abc${i}.tar abc${i} // --> tar abc directory
       mv abc.tar /tmp               // --> move tar file to  /tmp
       i=$(expr $i + 1)              //--> increase variable i by one for next iteration.

    done < DirList.txt
```

Comment: What if I have 
&quot;/xyz/test1/a1/&quot; &quot;/xyz/test2/b2/&quot; &quot;/xyz/test3/c3/&quot; directories and I need some a.tar b.tar and c.tar respectively

Comment: Either, we can remove  `&quot (')` from directory list, may be with -->  `sed  -i "s/'//g" DirList.txt`  or can use --> `cd $(echo $dirName | sed  "s/'//g" )`   in script itself to change the directory.

and to get `a.tar, b.tar` names, we can use a for loop for `tarfileName` as below
`for tarFileName in {a..z}`
`do`
    `# --> while loop goes inside - with changed tar command`
`done` , thanks

Comment: Sorry that how did that quots came . Please find find my query below 

"/xyz/test1/abc1/" "/xyz/test2/abc2/" "/xyz/test3/abc3/"

I need to tar some dir1.tar , dir2.tar and dir3.tar in respective locations

Comment: Sorry, i am not clear on "Sorry that how did that quots came" in your comment,
can you explain a little more, a screenshot perhaps ?

Comment: I have a requirement like below. 
I need to go into each application target directory and generate a tar of application home.tar and copy the same to /tmp on the same machine.
The application directories look like below $/artifactserver/com/xyz/abc/ ls -lrt 
App1/ to
App16/
cd App1/target/
tar -cvf App1Home.tar App1Home/
cp -r App1Home.tar /tmp
cd ../..
cd App2/target/
tar -cvf App2Home.tar App2Home/
cp -r App2Home.tar /tmp

Answer (score 0):

@JithinScaria please find my query below

I have a requirement like below I need to do a build for multiple apps after doing the below

1. Git clone , git fetch and build by maven with a shell script.—> all these were taken care with a shell script.

   2. Now after all the apps were build I need to go into each application target directory and generate a tar of application home.tar and copy the same to /tmp on the same machine.

The application directories look like below 
$/artifactserver/com/xyz/abc/ 
ls  -lrt
 App1/
App2/ 
 App3/
App4/

Till

App16/

cd App1/target/

tar -cvf App1Home.tar App1Home/

cp -r App1Home.tar /tmp

cd ../..

cd App2/target/

tar -cvf App2Home.tar App2Home/

cp -r App2Home.tar /tmp

cd ../..

So on 
How can I achieve all these .tars and copy them to /tmp with block.

Answer (score 0):

I hope either one below will do your work,

**option 1:**

create a file with the list of **16** directories as below,

```
$cat DirList.txt
/artifactserver/com/xyz/abc/App1/target/
/artifactserver/com/xyz/abc/App2/target/
/artifactserver/com/xyz/abc/App3/target/
...
/artifactserver/com/xyz/abc/App16/target/
```

use the this file as input to while loop below,

```
i=1                              // **i** - incremental variable
while read dirName
do
   cd ${dirName}                         # --> change directory
   tar -cvf App${i}Home.tar App${i}Home/ # --> tar directory
   cp App${i}Home.tar /tmp               # --> copy tar file to  /tmp
   i=$(expr $i + 1)                      # --> increase variable i by one.
done < DirList.txt
```

**option 2:**

create a file with the list of **16** directories, tar filename and directory name to be tarred with a delimiter, here i used `|` as the delimiter

```
$cat DirList.txt
/artifactserver/com/xyz/abc/App1/target/|App1Home.tar|App1Home
/artifactserver/com/xyz/abc/App2/target/|App2Home.tar|App2Home
/artifactserver/com/xyz/abc/App3/target/|App3Home.tar|App3Home
...
/artifactserver/com/xyz/abc/App16/target/|App16Home.tar|App16Home
```

use the this file as input to while loop below,

```
while read line
do
   dirName=$(echo $line | awk -F'|' '{print $1}')  # --> assign first var to directory
   tarFile=$(echo $line | awk -F'|' '{print $2}')  # --> tar file name
   dirToTar=$(echo $line | awk -F'|' '{print $3}') # --> directory name to be tarred
   cd ${dirName}                                   # --> change directory
   tar -cvf ${tarFile} ${dirToTar}                 # --> tar directory
   cp ${tarFile} /tmp                              # --> copy tar file to  /tmp
done < DirList.txt
```

Comment: Option2 has served my request. Thanks