# `Argument list too long: '/bin/sh'`

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I'm trying to invoke `tar`  command via `subprocess` call from Python.The challenge I have is there are a lot files that get passed on to `tar` which is causing the command to throw the error `Argument list too long: '/bin/sh'`

The command I'm running is below

```
subprocess.call(f"ulimit -s 99999999; tar -cz -f {output_file} {file_list}", cwd=source_dir, shell=True)
```

To try to overcome the error, I added `ulimit` which doesn't seem to help. The OS I am running this on is Ubuntu-20.04 & Pyhon version is 3.8

Please could I get help to solve this problem.

Comment: Try a level of indirection and put the list in a file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033857/tar-archiving-that-takes-input-from-a-list-of-files (maybe called `mlylist.txt` and add `-T mylist.txt` to the tar command)

Comment: You can't control the maximum length of the command line, unless you recompile the sources. BTW, `ulimit -s` sets the maximum stack size.

Comment: Aside from the clever idea of doctorlove: Can you maybe copy the files to some temporary directory (which you erase afterwards)? Then you just pass to `tar` the directory name.

Comment: Please do not multi-post across stacks (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/679620/117549)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ulimit` does nothing to lift the kernel constant `ARG_MAX` which is what you are bumping into here. In fact, the only way to increase it is typically to recompile your kernel.

If your `tar` supports `--files-from -`, use that.

```
subprocess.check_call(
    ['tar', '-cz', '-f', output_file, '--files-from', '-'],
    input='\n'.join(file_list), cwd=source_dir)
```

I obviously made assumptions about the contents of `file_list` (in particular, this will break if you have files whose name contains a newline character). Notice also how I [avoid `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) by passing in the command as a list of strings.

Of course, a much better solution for this use case is to use [the Python `tarfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) to create the `tar` file; this entirely avoids the need to transmit the list of file names across a process boundary.

```
import tarfile

with tarfile.open(output_file, "x:gz") as tar:
    for name in file_list:
        tar.add(name)
```

The `"x:gz"` mode of creation triggers an exception if the file already exists (use `"w:gz"` to simply overwrite).